# How can I change document elements by webExtension when user click on extension icon in toolbar?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to create a webExtension and I want to have icon in toolbar for this extension.
In my manifest.json file I put this code:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "test",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "test",
"icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "96": "icons/icon96.png"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "contextMenus"
],

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "19": "button/btn19.png",
        "38": "button/btn38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "test"
}
}
```

When user click on this extension icon in toolbar, I want to get elements of current page and add < a > tag in document where I want. I put this java script code in background.js file. But these code doesn't execute.
How can I fix this?

background.js :

```
function change() {
var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");  
var re = new RegExp(/abba\b/g);
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var str = elems[i].innerHTML;
    if (!str.match(/<[a-zA-Z0-9\s:./\"\'=\\;()-_]*>/) && re.test(str)) {
        var aTag = document.createElement("a");
        aTag.setAttribute('href', "test.php?t=" + str.match(/abba\b/)[0]);
        aTag.setAttribute('target', "_blank");
        aTag.innerHTML = " --**CHANGES**-- ";
        elems[i].appendChild(aTag);
    }
}
}
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(change);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background pages do not have access to the contents of the web page.

You need to use content scripts. Content scripts are injected into the page after page load on idle

Get more information from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts)

to add a content script to your extension you can add this to `manifest.json`

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],
    "js": ["contentscript.js"]
 }]
```

and then rename `background.js` to `contentscript.js`. This way the code is always executed on each page.

Or alternatively just create `contentscript.js` and move the contents `change()` function into it

contentscript.js:

```
var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");  
var re = new RegExp(/abba\b/g);
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var str = elems[i].innerHTML;
    if (!str.match(/<[a-zA-Z0-9\s:./\"\'=\\;()-_]*>/) && re.test(str)) {
        var aTag = document.createElement("a");
        aTag.setAttribute('href', "test.php?t=" + str.match(/abba\b/)[0]);
        aTag.setAttribute('target', "_blank");
        aTag.innerHTML = " --**CHANGES**-- ";
        elems[i].appendChild(aTag);
    }
}
```

then `background.js` will call `tabs.executeScript()` when browser action clicked.  This way it is only called when necessary

background.js:

```
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){ 
    browser.tabs.executeScript({file: "/contentscript.js"})
});
```